Can I directly connect an MCU ADC pin to shunt resistor without worrying about damaging MCU from shunt resistor voltage?
I need to measure up to 80 amps from my 42 Volt DC battery. I am planning on using a shunt resistor in series with the negative terminal of the battery with my microcontroller measuring the voltage like the circuit below:

Is this okay to connect my microcontroller ADC pin directly to the shunt resistor since it is only a 0.01 resistor which I would think would not be above my microcontroller max input of 3.3 volts? Or do I need a voltage divider circuit to ensure the voltage drop across the resistor is less than my max microcontroller input voltage?

I'm disturbed to see only one connection from R2 to My_MCU_ADC. Your ADC likely measures voltage with respect to its GND or VREF- pin. How do you intend to connect the other end of R2 to your MCU? Please also show your MCU's relevant ADC connection pins. Is it differential ADC or single-ended? Does it have reference voltage input(s)? How is your MCU powered?

@glen_geek it is a single ended ADC. the other end is connected to the same ground potential as the 42V

And how is that MCU powered? This is a potential problem if you intend to power it from that same 42|V battery.

@glen_geek I am using a DC-DC buck converter that converts it to 3.3V. I'm not powering it with 42 volts

It's likely that you should also be worried about negative excursions especially if the load is somewhat inductive so, the first thing I'd do is insert a 1 kΩ resistor between the shunt and the MCU's ADC input. That will limit current into the pin and, most MCUs will tell you how much that is in the data sheet.
If your MCU data sheet suggests the input current can be up to 1 mA then the voltage at the top of the shunt can rise a volt above 3.3 volts before it might become a problem i.e. the 1 kΩ resistor drops 1 volt with 1 mA flowing. Of course you might choose a 10 kΩ resistor but again, read the data sheet to see that a pin used as an ADC input won't get messed up with a series 10 kΩ (you might need to add a capacitor to ground to fix it).
Under fault conditions however, there could be other problems. Consider what happens when the shunt fails open circuit and 80 volts (via the load) appears at the top pin of where the shunt formerly connected. It's a case of how far do you want to go to fix fault situations.

You may not need a voltage divider but some series resistance could preven an early death of your MCU should there be a surge that causes voltage to go below 0V or above 3.3V.
Many MCU ADCs are okay with 2.5kΩ to 10kΩ source resistance (which would effectively equal the series resistor here since the shunt is so low value).
For example, if your load had a small amount of capacitance and you switched it on, the voltage at the shunt would go up to much more than 3.3V briefly, and with extremely low source impedance. That's almost guaranteed to destroy the MCU if connected directly. Even if there is no significant capacitance, a tiny amount of stray series inductance can have serious effects:


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Your schematic is ambiguous. One interpretation is (roughly) this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Your sense resistor is in series with wires/traces with non-negligible resistance. For large currents, we typically use a Kelvin connection, and then sense the voltage differentially, with a differential amplifier or ADC.
In any case, it's good to put some series resistance between the high voltage/high current circuit and the low voltage/low current circuit monitoring it. Some sort of voltage clamp may also be desirable. Limit both voltage and current to safe values.

Here's a clamp that will protect the ADC, to a great extent:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The zener diode prevents node B from rising above +4V or so. In the event that node A rises beyond +4V, R2 will limit current somewhat. If A's potential rises beyond +20V, power in R2 will exceed 250mW, and it will burn out, hopefully open-circuit. You could employ a fusible resistor for R2, to guarantee that it would fail open.
Node B is clamped at +4V maximum, and -0.7V minimum by D1. ADC input protection diodes would conduct heavily at those extremes, if connected directly to B, but R3 limits the resulting current to a level that won't kill them and the ADC. A pessimistic estimate for maximum input current would be:
$$ I_{IN(MAX)} = \frac{0.7V}{1k\Omega} = 0.7mA $$
R2 and R3 are small compared to ADC input resistance, and shouldn't affect the potential "seen" by the ADC for measurement.
